# How to match everything except a particular pattern after/before a specific string constant

Tags: regex, emacs

```
ATS(inline, const, unused) /* Variadic Macro */
OTS(inline, const, unused)
```

I'm trying to match `inline`, `const`, `unused` keywords *only* in `ATS` macro.
i tried `ATS([^,]*)` but it only matches `inline` keyword.

**Edit**:
I need to change the color of all `ATS` parameters. this only works on the first parameter.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("ATS(\\([^,]*\\)" 1 font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

Comment: Please be specific. Show how you would use what you are asking for. is this for incremental search? Interactive or from Lisp? Do you want to match each keyword separately or do you want the list of keywords? Do you have lots of `ATS(...)` contexts or few? Etc. IOW, *specify* the problem.

Comment: are the matches all lowercase ?

Comment: @Drew, i want to add all the keywords inside ATS to be in another color. `("ATS(\\([^,]*\\))"  1 font-lock-builtin-face)`

Comment: Just the keywords, not the commas? Anyway, sounds like you want to add one or more patterns to `font-lock-keywords`. I will delete my answer that guessed that you were searching or replacing text etc.

Comment: @Drew, Just the keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an *anchored* font-lock rule. It's like a search within a search. The code below searches for `AST(`. Once it's found, it find the end of the argument list and performs a search for all words within it.

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (setq font-lock-multiline t)
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("\\_<ATS("
      ("\\_<\\sw+\\_>"
       ;; Pre-match form -- limit the sub-search to the end of the argument list.
       (save-excursion
         (goto-char (match-end 0))
         (backward-char)
         (ignore-errors
           (forward-sexp))
         (point))
       ;; Post-match form
       (goto-char (match-end 0))
       (0 font-lock-builtin-face))))))
```

This will match all words inside the parentheses, even if they are spread out across multiple lines.

The pre-match form has two purposes: It can position the point to a suitable locations and it controls the extend of the sub-search (where `nil` means the end of the line). The post-match form can, for example, be used to return the point to a good position for other keyword rules.

This can, of course, be extended to only highlight a specific set of words, but I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: WoW \o/, and i just created `.emacs.d/emacs-monster` directory to clone all of your elisp repositories.., now i can make modes lol.

Answer (score 0):

If the matches are all lower case, you can simply use:

```
[a-z]+
```

Make sure the regex is case sensitive.

Comment: it still stops after first keyword: `inline`

Comment: Please post the complete regex you're using. Also, you need to loop the array with the results.

Comment: I'm trying to change the color of keywords inside ATS macro: `("ATS(\\([^,]*\\)" 1 font-lock-builtin-face)`. this only works on the first keyword.

Comment: You should update your question and post the ATS macro and the  full code you're using to replace, that way i can see what's wrong.

Comment: I udated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way:

Load library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([**`highlight.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el))

Then invoke command/function `foo`:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end "ATS([^)]*\\(inline\\)[^)]*)"
                               'font-lock-builtin-face  nil nil 1)
  (hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end "ATS([^)]*\\(const\\)[^)]*)"
                               'font-lock-constant-face nil nil 1)
  (hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end "ATS([^)]*\\(unused\\)[^)]*)"
                               'font-lock-warning-face  nil nil 1))
```

You can also do the same thing using `font-lock-add-keywords`.

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("ATS([^)]*\\(inline\\)[^)]*)" (1 'font-lock-builtin-face t)))
                          'APPEND)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("ATS([^)]*\\(const\\)[^)]*)"  (1 'font-lock-constant-face t)))
                          'APPEND)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("ATS([^)]*\\(unused\\)[^)]*)" (1 'font-lock-warning-face t)))
                          'APPEND))
```

And if you know that they will all occur in the same `ATS` sexp, in the same order, then you can combine the separate regexps into one and use a single call to either `hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end` or `font-lock-add-keywords`.

Comment: Thanks Drew, but isn't there a way without specifying exact keywords in elisp (matching *any* keyword) or without using external elisp libraries?

Comment: Wait a bit and see if you don't get a more elegant answer. You can change which answer you accept as *"the" answer* at any time (and any number of times, I think). With luck, you will see multiple interesting answers, providing different degrees of enlightenment.

Comment: the `font-lock` version worked so far. thanks again. but i guess in case i wanted to play with parameters (repeat them for example if i forget that i set `unused` flag before: `ATS(unused, inline, const, unused)` i should ask RMS himself!